# Determine tapped element within UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uikit

I have an `UICollectionView` with custom cells. When I tap a cell I get a `collectionView: didSelectItemAtIndexPath:`.

This doesn't allow me to determine which element inside the cell was tapped (image or label). How to determine which element within the cell was tapped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to subclass `UICollectionViewCell` and have these kind of objects in your `UICollectioView`. Then you create a `delegate` in the cells with methods like

```
- (void)collectionCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell didTapButtonWithIndex:(NSUInteger)index
```

and set your view controller as delegate for each of this cell. So you would get the action in these methods instead of `collectionView: didSelectItemAtIndexPath:`

Comment: I did not see that UICollectionViewCell has a delegate. I checked Apple's IOS reference, I did not see any delegate method like this:  `(void)collectionCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell didTapButtonWithIndex:(NSUInteger)index`.

Comment: It doesn't exist, you have to create this protocol

Answer (score 2):

You can set a tap `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the entire cell and use `- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;` to get the tapped object

In `-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`
do this

```
 UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(cellTapped:)];
    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [cell addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
```

And in `cellTapped`

```
-(void)cellTapped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    CGPoint tapPoint = [gesture locationInView:gesture.view];
    UIView *tappedView = [gesture.view hitTest:tapPoint withEvent:nil];

    if ([tappedView isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
        NSLog(@"Found");
    }
}
```

Please do check to see whether the user interaction is set on the cell and individual subviews like labels and imageview's . Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the cell element when creating the cell in `cellForItem` and add target and selector to call. The selector method will then get a recognizer which has a `UIView` property, and this property will be your selected element.